# Expected X to define Y - class and module with same name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this:

```
# /app/events/account_cancelled.rb:
module Events
  class AccountCancelled < Base::TrackEvent

#/app/events/base/track_event.rb:
module Events
  module Base
    class TrackEvent < Event

#/app/services/website/base.rb:
module Services
  module Website
    class Base
```

I get an error:

```
Expected <snip>/app/services/website/base.rb to define Base
   from <snip>/app/events/account_cancelled.rb:2
```

I tried fully qualifying the class definition of `AccountCancelled` thusly:

```
module Events
  class AccountCancelled < Events::Base::TrackEvent
```

But I get the exact same error.  Incidentally, everything worked until I moved all this from `lib` to `app`.  What's going on here?

**UPDATE**:

I also tried inheriting from `::Events::Base::TrackEvent`.  Same error.

Answer (score -1):

`/app/events/account_cancelled.rb` expects `::Base` or `Events::Base`, but 
`/app/services/website/base.rb:` gives `Services::Website::Base`. They don't match.

Comment: I'm not following you. ```Events::AccountCancelled``` should derive from ```Events::Base::TrackedEvent```.  ```Services::Website::Base``` should be no part of it.  Maybe if you can show how I should change my code I could understand your point better. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how inheritance is relevant. I do not intend to show any further than this.

Comment: What does it mean "...account_cancelled.rb expects ::Base or Events::Base", and how is it anyhow related to ```Services::Website::Base```?